# django sql thread safe?

Tags: mysql, django, multithreading, view

Assume I have this code:

```
product = Product.objects.get(name='something')
product.number_sold += 1
product.save()
```

if during the query number_sold was 10, and then before the save(), this code run at the same time so the query will return 10 again, it means it will save number_sold = 11 twice ?
In other words, can two users running this django view can get the same value for number_sold field ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid race condition in your multi-thread/process code you should use the [`F()-expressions`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions):

```
from django.db.models import F

product = Product.objects.get(name='something')
product.number_sold = F('number_sold') + 1
product.save()
```

Comment: I read about the F expressions,  still my question is still there - is it still possible that two users get the same number_sold with the given code?
And if I will decorate my view with @transaction.atomic, is that guarantee that all the queries will perform on the same db state ?
the question code is just an example.

Comment: Yes, it is possible that two users will get the same `number_sold` in memory, but at db level `number_sold` will be different after each `save()`.  If you will add `@transaction.atomic` then you will get an exception in some of your threads. To prevent such exceptions you can use the `select_for_update()` method = https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in a single query:

```
Product.objects.filter(name='something').update(number_sold=F('number_sold')+1)
```